# Sign a new cert in Azure Key Vault by an existing certificate

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, hsm

How can I sign a newly created Key Vault stored certificate's CSR by another Key Vault stored certificate (internally, just like an HSM, without having to extract the private key to the C# runtime)?

Comment: any luck finding an answer?

Comment: No, Stackoverflow seems partially dead or the pro guys left it.